# Capture One 12 edit in Photoshop get back with transparent background

Tags: photoshop, capture-one

I need to remove the background of a series of product shots and keep the shadows of the product.

Hence, I in Capture One 12 (CO) go for *edit in Photoshop*, exported as TIFF as well as PSD. Did my work and saved the finished edits.

But in CO I always get back the image with white background. I read in the [CO external editing documentation](https://help.phaseone.com/en/CO12/Editing-photos/External-Editing) that the images are flattened on reading them in in CO again.

Is there no way to get back the edited image with transparencies/alpha channel? I really can't imagine it's not possible.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CaptureOne, but I can certainly imagine dealing with alpha channels to be out of scope because that's not the main use case. What's your reason for bringing the images back into CaptureOne and not just doing the pixel manipulation kind of work in Photoshop?

Comment: As mattdm wrote, this might well be an XY-problem. Please tell us what you try to accomplish by putting them into C1 again.

Comment: As I want to have them consistent in color correction, crop and positioning of the products, it would be helpful to get them back into the CO session to position and crop them. Also to export them with the same settings. For sure this can be done on PS as well, but I thought it's a good idea to have them back in CO...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, C1 does not support alpha channels. That might be because photos typically offer no alpha channel.

You say that you want consistent color correction, crop and positioning of your photos - I would suggest that you get those things done first in C1, then export the pictures for use in Photoshop.

Comment: By a quick googling, I found this: https://blog.captureone.com/whats-new-capture-one-pro-9-1/ Here they claim, CO supports alpha channels in TIFFs since CO 9.1. But the information is sparse to say at least...

Comment: I am afraid, they just support alpha channels in tetherd shooting overlay mode: https://help.phaseone.com/en/CO12/Tethered-Capture/Overlay-tool

Comment: I think it's a bit of a pity, it's not possible to have the images without background to correct them. Color perception changes really depending on the surrounding areas. But it seems, that's how it is for now...

Comment: The documentation reads like this: 
"Other file support Layered Tiff: Capture One 9.1 onward can support Tiff files with alpha channel or layers saved in the file (from other apps like Adobe Photoshop) but for viewing purposes only. Reprocessing the image will result in a new flattened image. PSD: Capture 10.1 onward can support PSD files in the viewer. The PSD can contain any adjustments, layers, text or smart objects but must be saved in Photoshop with “maximize compatibility” enabled. Peprocessing the image from Capture One will result in a new flattened image."